# Create a custom map in android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, maps, android-canvas

I need to create a simple map application for android. 
It's something along the lines of [this one](http://idw.altervista.org/webapp/) I made in HTML5 some time ago called [CanvaMap](http://blog.fdev.eu/canvamap/). 
I need to replicate it's features for Android. It can be zoomed in, dragged around and some of the buildings (the ones on the left) have floor plans that are shown when zooming. It also manages events such as click and double-click.

I don't know whether I should use Android's Canvas, OpenGL 2D, or anything else. I need it to be fast and lightweight, and possibly work with Android 2.3 onward.

Are there any open source applications/frameworks/engines that do anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been pointed to this library: [MapView by moagrius](https://github.com/moagrius/MapView), which seems to partially fulfill my needs.